# Placing a sign, given from a generator, not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using the [Animated Scoreboard](http://mctoolbox.me/animate/) sign generator. The problem is that when I place the sign that the generator gave me, the sign looks like this: [image: Non-working sign...]

As you can see the content is `""` instead of `Click Here`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I use Minecraft 1.9 with OptiFine 1.9 pre 04.

Also note: I am doing this on a vanilla server.

The command I use that is generated can be found here: http://pastebin.com/VehNSpnx

Comment: Have you tried it *without* Optifine? If it still doesn't work in plain vanilla, you should provide the command you used to obtain the sign.

Comment: @Skylinerw Ok, I'll try it in vanilla.

Comment: @Skylinerw I added a pastebin link with the command.

Comment: The command you've provided works fine. It's Optifine interfering. Command mechanics rarely work well with mods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 1.8 version of Minecraft then the problem could be that  you are using the 1.9 version of Sign Generator.

I recommend using https://minecraftcommand.science/command-sign-generator for any 1.8 signs.

Another problem could be mods you have downloaded.  If you have an older version of Minecraft and you are using a higher version mod/ or vice versa then that could be causing the problem.  Both are trying to use different versions of Minecraft causing disruptions.

Comment: I use Minecraft 1.9 with only OptiFine 1.9 pre 04 installed.

Comment: @CommandFox Try using the 1.8 Sign generator anyway maybe the one you're using is incomplete.

Comment: The problem is that that is not a sign generator. It is something that generates an animated scoreboard. So you have to right click the sign for it to work. It's like a one command operation.

Comment: I see. I needed to look closer

Comment: I can only think that mods are causing this then.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm only using OptiFine by the way. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: I had a problem like this while I used WorldEdit 1.7.10 on a 1.8 world. If you have mods try updating them.

Comment: I don't really use any mods though.

Comment: I'll look into it more to try answer your problem.

Comment: A 1.9 generator will work in 1.8. The text component has simply been changed to use strict JSON, which was already possible in the past and is essentially no different if you were already using strict JSON. There would be an issue the other way around: if the generator is meant for 1.8 and does not create strict JSON, it will fail in 1.9.